# Allow users select file from google drvie to upload to my server

Tags: c#, google-drive-api

I'm building a mobile-friendly website (not mobile app) using .Net MVC (with Razor).

I want the users to select single word / pdf/ txt file from their Google Drive and upload it to my `websites` just like to would upload regular file.

So far I found the API to download files, but it's not helping, they shouldn't save the file, just upload (post) it.

Any idea would be great, thanks

Comment: You need to download the file from Drive to your site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The users will need to be authenticated first using oauth2.

**Authentcation**

```
/// <summary>
        /// Authenticate to Google Using Oauth2
        /// Documentation https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="clientId">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="clientSecret">From Google Developer console https://console.developers.google.com</param>
        /// <param name="userName">A string used to identify a user.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static DriveService AuthenticateOauth(string clientId, string clientSecret, string userName)
        {

            //Google Drive scopes Documentation:   https://developers.google.com/drive/web/scopes
            string[] scopes = new string[] {                                                  DriveService.Scope.DriveFile   // view and manage files created by this app
};                                                

            try
            {
                // here is where we Request the user to give us access, or use the Refresh Token that was previously stored in %AppData%
                UserCredential credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(new ClientSecrets { ClientId = clientId, ClientSecret = clientSecret }
                                                                                             , scopes
                                                                                             , userName
                                                                                             , CancellationToken.None
                                                                                             , new FileDataStore("Daimto.Drive.Auth.Store")).Result;

                DriveService service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
                {
                    HttpClientInitializer = credential,
                    ApplicationName = "Daimto Drive API Sample",
                });
                return service;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                Console.WriteLine(ex.InnerException);
                return null;

            }

           }
```

**download**

```
 /// <summary>
        /// Download a file
        /// Documentation: https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/files/get
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="_service">a Valid authenticated DriveService</param>
        /// <param name="_fileResource">File resource of the file to download</param>
        /// <param name="_saveTo">location of where to save the file including the file name to save it as.</param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static Boolean downloadFile(DriveService _service, File _fileResource, string _saveTo)
        {

            if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(_fileResource.DownloadUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    var x = _service.HttpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(_fileResource.DownloadUrl );
                    byte[] arrBytes = x.Result;
                    System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(_saveTo, arrBytes);
                    return true;                  
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + e.Message);
                    return false;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // The file doesn't have any content stored on Drive.
                return false;
            }
        }
```

code riped from [Google dotnet samples google drive](https://github.com/LindaLawton/Google-Dotnet-Samples/tree/master/Google-Drive) tutorial [Google Drive service account](http://www.daimto.com/google-drive-api-with-a-service-account/)

Comment: Hi, perhaps I wasn't clear. I dont want to add the file to my Google Drive account, I want to save them as files on my server.

Comment: Upldated it: You can use service.Files.List(); to get a list of the files on there drive for them to select for download.  theres a method in the sample project called  GetFiles that should help